# Cover marked squares with rectangles with optimal tradeoff

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, python

I'm trying to solve this problem where I have to cover all the squares in a N x N grid with rectangles with a tradeoff between cost and computation. These are the constraints:

- Fields are rectangular, but may be of any width or height
- Rectangles may cover any cell whether marked or not
- Must be rectangular
- Must be axis-aligned with the grid (i.e., not diagonal)
- Rectangles cannot overlap
- Each rectangle costs 10 + 5 per unit of area covered

Some possible solutions are given below:

[image]

I would ideally want to create a random array and test out the code for this. Grid can be any size with any number of marked squares. Optimal solution would be a balanced solution between lowest cost and lowest computational cost.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to credit where you encountered this task?

Comment: (I would hope for the cost of another rectangle to exceed twice that of covering one *unit of area*. Even as specified above, minimal cost for example 2 is ≤ 99.)

Comment: What is your question, and what is the [CS angle](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: It's to find an optimal algorithm that will fit the constraints above

Comment: Please [edit] the question to state your question.  What counts as an optimal algorithm?  Do you mean an algorithm to find the lowest-cost solution?  I don't know what is meant by "the tradeoff is cost vs computation".

Comment: Edited the question, essentially find an optimal solution that finds a balance between lowest cost to build and lowest computational cost to solve the problem.